# What is the minimum value of $(\tan^2)(A/2)+(\tan^2)(B/2)+(\tan^2)(C/2)$, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are angles of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

> What is the minimum value of $(\tan^2)(A/2)+(\tan^2)(B/2)+(\tan^2)(C/2)$, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are angles of a triangle?

I know that the sum of the angles is $\pi$, but I am unable to find the minimum value of the above expression.

Comment: Note that $A + B + C = \pi$.

Comment: I know that A+B+C=π

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigonometric Functions And Identities Question .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337628/trigonometric-functions-and-identities-question)

Comment: @MANMAID, you are right it is almost same as the one you stated. But do you even realise, it took you 3 years to search for that question, How was I supposed to find that question when I had to know the answer then. I can't keep waiting for 3 years just to find the answer of 1 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan(C/2)=\tan(\pi/2-(A+B)/2)=\frac{1}{\tan((A+B)/2)}=\frac{1-\tan(A/2)\tan(B/2)}{\tan(A/2)+\tan(B/2)}$
Let $a=\tan(A/2), b=\tan(B/2), c=\tan(C/2)$, all positive, the constraint becomes
$$c=(1-ab)/(a+b)$$ which is equivalent to $ab+bc+ca=1$ 
I'll leave you to prove $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$ and only equal when $a,b,c$ are all equal.

Answer (score 6):

Just another way:  noting $\tan^2 \frac x 2$ is convex, by Jensen's inequality you have
$$\tan^2\frac A 2 + \tan^2 \frac B 2 + \tan^2 \frac C 2 \ge 3\tan^2\frac{A+B+C}{2\cdot 3 } = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry it occurs  when triangle is equilateral, when  $ A/2 = \pi/6 ; $

Minimum value $ 1/3 + 1/3 +1/3 =1.$